# What will be the output ripple current per capacitor buck regulator?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, voltage-regulator, buck, ripple-current

I have a existing buck regulator design. Converter part number: [TPS54340Q1](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54340-q1.pdf).

Input voltage = 5 V.
Output voltage = 3.3 V

RMS ripple current is calculated as = 108 mA. (Don't worry too much about value. Conider the value for mathematical analysis)

**I have two decoupling capacitors at the output:**

a) Cout1 = 1 uF, ESR1 - 110 mOhm

b) Cout2 =  4.7 uF, ESR2 - 120 mOhm

Switching frequency = 500 kHz.

> Question 1

I just need to calculate how ripple current will be split between Cout1 and Cout 2. I mean how will be ratio.

Can we do the current splitting just as we do with two parallel resistors for ESR1 and ESR2?

> Question 2

Assume we got the value for each capacitor ripple current. How can make sure that the existing decoupling capacitor is enough to withstand the ripple current passing through it. 
( I checked for rated current value in capacitors datasheet, there is no such parameters with ceramic capacitors but yes, there is rated current for tantalum capacitors. My output capacitor is ceramic type)

Done some research on internet from my end,but there was not much I could not find.

**EDIT**:

Cout1 Capacitor [link](https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/Murata-Electronics/GRM188R71C105KE15D?qs=eeBpzGFlv%252b%252bcTe8zfRKqyA%3D%3D)

Cout2 Capacitor [link](https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/Murata-Electronics/GRM21BR71C475KA73L?qs=sGAEpiMZZMs0AnBnWHyRQHfJxnYD9SALbgB5Ts5BRWk%3D)

Comment: A link to both capacitors would prove useful I'm sure.

Comment: Can compute apparent Impedance of RC at 500kHz and harmonics? Then divide V(f) / Zc(f) for each cap and load R.

Comment: @Andyaka, added the link

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt, You mean Z = R + (1/jWC) ?

Comment: What is your ripple spec and what RLCRCR filter is needed to achieve it. Be sure you measure ripple into an impedance matched 50 ohm AC coupled scope. No I mean square root of square R^2+X(f)^2

Comment: @vt673 how did you discover the ESRs of those capacitors?

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt, 0.165 V is the maximum output ripple voltage allowed. I am bit confused with the term RLCRCR filter. Kindly elaborate if time permits. It will be helpful for me.

Comment: @Andyaka, There was no ESR value in the datasheet. I have taken values for analysis purpose.

Comment: These letters suggest possible equivalent circuit components for your filter analysis in series and shunt. Beware of parallel resonance.model it accurately and simulate it in f domain eg. Falstad and measure accurately

Comment: Also and cap worth using must have a low ESR specified

Comment: @vt673 those values will be probably about 50 times too high. It might be prudent to find a capacitor that has a data sheet that indicated the graph of its resonant series frequency and look at the bottom of the curve to understand what the practical ESR will be. The Murata data sheet looks like it was written by a "committee" who kind of missed the point of what engineers need to study!!

Comment: I agree with @Andyaka, your ESR values are way too high for ceramic or even polymer caps that would be used in a buck converter.  Murata's datasheets can be terrible, but they have an online calculator tool that can provide impedance and ESR graphs for most of their capacitors, as well as DC voltage derating.  I find it very useful: http://ds.murata.co.jp/simsurfing/index.html?lcid=en-us

Comment: GRM’s Cheapest multipurpose ceramic while KR3 would be your best performance

Comment: KR3 value with SRF at buck f can yield ESR 50 mOhm

Comment: All your answers are on the web if you the best “key words”. Practice harder.

Comment: Just an observation, Can calculate the ESR using Dissipation factor, ESR=DF*Xc.